# Efecto de carrusel que divide imagenes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animación

Disculpen que el título no sea tan especifico pero es que quiero hacer un efecto de transición de imágenes donde la imagen se divide en partes y se reconstruye parecido a esta pagina https://www.cidecuador.com/ ¿Como hago esos efectos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen dia,
El efecto que deseas realizar se hace mediante css (a veces tienes que incluir jquery o Javascript). En base a la pagina que brindaste, ellos utilizaron un editor o creador de pagina llamado [Wix](https://es.wix.com/)

Si deseas realizar este efecto en tu propia web, te recomiendo busques efectos para transiciones de imagenes en sliders, como por ejemplo:[Javascript Image Slider](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider) , el cual te brinda demos gratuitas y con efectos que pueden serte de utilidad(incluido el que necesitas)

Saludos.

Comment: Si me fijé que usaron wix, pero ese efecto es brutalmente fenomenal, aunque el que me pasaste está muy bueno, lo voy a implementar, muchas gracias